# Store Videos in MySQL Output in HTML Via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, video, video-streaming

how do I put urls of videos in mysql and be able to call them by clicking on a thumbnail or button as well as in the webs of movies:

[image: first image]
[image: Second image]

Comment: You are asking +2 questions here. Please define where you are having issues; e.g. storing, retrieving, playing, etc.

Comment: storing and consulting please  :'(

Comment: Please add your current storage attempts in that case so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Your question is too board. It is not a problem to store the URL as a string in the database. Afterwards you can get this string and embed somehow on your UI. Youtube even offers some code snippets for that

Comment: You are simply asking for another person to code it for you... please do some PHP +Mysql tutorials. it's the same as Image, Text or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a column/field of type VARCHAR(300) called **video_url** that will be used to store the video URLs. Then you retrieve and play the videos in your HTML using the following code:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('video_player').style.display='block'">
  Play Video
</button>

<video id="video_player" style="display:none;" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="<?=video_url?>" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: `<?=video_url?>` that should produce an undefined constant error.

Comment: TINYTEXT? That is not adviced beter is to use `VARCHAR(255)` newer MySQL versions support a even greater value `VARCHAR(65535)` or `VARCHAR(21844)` (when using UTF8).. In InnoDB `...TEXT`  datatypes are stored seprated from the table table meaning extra I/O to fetch the data..

Comment: Yh that's true he would need to retrieve the video_url variable in PHP from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RaymondNijland. I'll update the solution.